# Fluentd - Use variable from inside the data in logfile-name

Tags: ruby, fluentd

I'm fairly new to fluentd and I am not sure if it can do what I am trying right now. I am using it to collect log-data from a whole bunch of Docker-containers running on the same host, so the "hostname"-variable that is often discussed is not helping me. Instead, the log-data I receive includes a field "container_name".
Now what I would like is to have Fluentd write log-files with a name of "container_name-id_timestamp" but none of the ways I've tried so far have worked. I do not know how to evaluate fields from within the data packet.

I went ahead and matched everything like this:

```
<match *.**>
   type file
   path /var/log/fluent/
   time_slice_format %Y-%m-%d
   time_slice_wait 10m
   time_format %Y-%m-%dT-%H-%M-%S-%z
</match>
```

And then tried all kinds of variables like

```
path /var/log/fluent/${container_name}_%Y-%m-%d
```

or

```
path /var/log/fluent/${tag_parts[2]}_%Y-%m-%d
```

But instead of interpreting it takes it literal. What am I missing?
I'd also be fine with subfolders for each container, which I am having the same problem with.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anyone coming here looking for a solution, I've found out how to do it:

```
<match docker.*>
 type rewrite_tag_filter
 rewriterule1 container_name ^\/(.*)$ tagged.$1
</match>

<match tagged.*>
 type forest
 subtype file
 remove_prefix service
 <template>
 time_slice_format %Y-%m-%d
 path /var/log/fluentd/${tag}.*.log
 </template>

</match>
```

What is happening?

1. Look for a match to i.e. the docker.325435abcd-tag
2. Use fluent_plugin_rewrite_tag_filter to get the container_name from within the data
3. Rewrite the tag with the container_name
4. Match the tagged data
5. Use the forest_plugin to template the log-file-name to use the tag
6. Done